# Custom List: Radio Buttons field stores 1 & 0 - Any fix?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I have a basic custom list in SharePoint Online which consists of many fields and one of them is Radio Buttons (True / False) field, For some strange reason, When users fill the form, All values get stored correctly except this particular field, It stores 0 or 1 .... Why this behavior?

There are no customization and it is behaving this way !

When user fills the form i.e. NewForm.aspx or Edit the form EditForm.aspx => The column's name and its values are showing correctly !

But, When the item is stored or , or View the form ViewForm.aspx => The column's name shows correctly, But the value shows 1 or 0  !!

Any idea why is this and how to fix it?

Other lists are working fine - I need to fix this particular list because creating a new one or even save a template is not an option !

Comment: I can't replicate this, but if I had this situation and needed to fix it urgently, I would put add a period to the options: `True.` and `False.`